# How to deploy Windows 10 IoT (Rasp Pi image) as a Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, iot, windows-10

Is it possible to deploy Windows 10 IoT (Rasp Pi image) as a Virtual Machine using VirtualBox or VMWare Player?

I need for a testing lab a network of three to five Windows 10 IoT devices. A virtual cluster would be perfect. My Google- and Bing-based research failed.

The problem could be either the non-ISO disk image file format or the non-x86 architecture of the operating system, couldn't it?

Comment: Were you able to get the ffu provided by the Core IoT to run in qemu or VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found is downloading Windows 10 IoT Core for MinnowBoard MAX
(here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691712). This MinnowBoard is x86-based and the image comes in a .iso file. I know the OP was specific about being a Rasp Pi image, but I don't really see the difference if we're just trying to use a hypervisor. Afterwards, you may just follow this tutorial: http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/running-windows-10-iot-core-in-a-virtual-machine

It's very simple and straight-forward, and it works with VirtualBox.

Comment: I followed those instructions and everything went well until the machine startup where, instead of the Windows logo I just see a shell prompt. Is there an instruction to run after that?

Answer (score 2):

Based on @makoshichi's links here's the steps that worked for me:

- Download [MinnowBoard MAX IoT Core](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691712) from microsoft, and install
- Run [ImgMount](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2066903) tool as Admin to mount `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT\FFU\MinnowBoardMax\flash.ffu"`
- Detach the VHD from Disk Management (in Computer Management), move the resultant .vhd file (that it informs you of on detach) to a location of your choice
- Create, **but don't launch**, a new Virtual Machine in VirtualBox (expert mode) as Windows 32-bit, using an "existing virtual hard disk file" - the one you just moved
- Goto device `Settings->System` and click `Enable EFI (special OSes only)`
- Goto device `Settings->Network` and select `Bridged Adapater`

That's it - Run your virtual machine and be a happy Thing of the Internet, or something like that.

This is my short version of [this wonderful post by Yavor Ivanov](https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/running-windows-10-iot-core-in-a-virtual-machine).

Comment: Does ImgMount run on Windows 10. I couldn't get the version from xda forum to run. I guess I could use dism tool instead, right?

Comment: I just had to run as admin I think - can't remember now, sorry. Have you tried as admin and in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

The QEMU emulator may do it, it will boot the image file directly. you may need to expand the ffu with **dism** first.
You don't have to fully install w10 preview: just boot the W10 real or virtual DVD and select to open a cmd box, from there you can run the updated **dism** command.
**iot** w10 have no (direct) GUI, you must talk to the device via **winrm** and powershell
There is a good startup for you on 
[sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/) 

fc

Comment: Thanks, I'll gibt it a try!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/0xabu/qemu/tree/raspi is a working way to run Windows 10 IoT on Qemu. It fully emulates a RPi2, except USB

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use the Raspberry Pi Simulator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-web-simulator-get-started